# How to setup AS3 to communicate to remote server via sockets?

Tags: flash, node.js, crossdomain.xml

I have a basic mini game working with flash and node.js in my localhost, and I'm hoping to move the backend to a remote server. I've created an Amazon EC2 instance, installed node.js, npm and got it running and listening on port 1337. The thing is now I'm getting a sandbox security error in flash now. I'm using FlashDevelop and compiling with the "Use Network services" to true. I'm not sure how to handle the crossdomain.xml issue. Do I need to listen for a request within node.js for this specific file and output the contents?

My actionscript:

```
var host:String = "54.234.175.99";
Security.allowDomain(host);
Security.allowInsecureDomain(host);
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://" + host + ":" +  "1337");

xmlSocket = new XMLSocket(host, 1337);
xmlSocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, onData);
xmlSocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
xmlSocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
```

In node I'm using the net module for communication with flash via sockets:

```
var net = require('net');
```

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

```
socket.on("connect", function(client){
    console.log('new flash client connected')
});

var data_buffer=''; 
socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('received data'+data);
            // do stuff with data 


});
```

Comment: Similar question here, may be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368576/sending-data-from-flash-to-node-js-server-with-socket-io

Comment: Thanks, it's similar, but I'm using the net module instead of socket.io in node, and I'm not sure how to listen and output the policy file... I can't find an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Flash demanding a crossdomain.xml file when the .swf and http target are both on localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222499/why-is-flash-demanding-a-crossdomain-xml-file-when-the-swf-and-http-target-are)